# Pointers, structures, and input

Tags: c, pointers, structure, scanf

So I made this program that asks the user for the time in the following format:
HH:MM:SS
And I've got the code for it down.. except for one thing. 
Let's assume the user enters something like this:
`12`
At this point, since the user hit 'enter', I want the program to display an error.
So, this is my problem: if the user enters `12:42141` (or something else along those lines)
I would like the program to stop instead of having scanf waiting for the 3 integers.
How do I code that?

Anyway, here's the actual program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

struct Time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

void AddOneSecond(struct Time *timePtr);
int CheckForErrors(struct Time timeVars, char charOne, char charTwo);

int main()
{
    auto char firstColon;
    auto char secondColon;
    auto int secondsAdded;
    auto int errorCheck;
    struct Time userInput;

    // Menu prompt
    printf("Enter the start time in HH:MM:SS format: ");
    scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", &userInput.hours
                          , &firstColon
                          , &userInput.minutes
                          , &secondColon
                          , &userInput.seconds);

    // Check for errors
    errorCheck = CheckForErrors(userInput, firstColon, secondColon);

    // If the input format is correct, proceed with the program. If it's not,
    // display an error message and terminate the program.
    if (errorCheck)
    {
        printf("How many seconds would you like to add? ");
        scanf("%d", &secondsAdded);

        // Loop that calls the 'AddOneSecond' function 'secondsAdded' amount
        // of times.
        for (int i = 0; i < secondsAdded; i++)
        {
            AddOneSecond(&userInput);

            printf("%02d:%02d:%02d \n", userInput.hours
                                      , userInput.minutes
                                      , userInput.seconds);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Error reading input...");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

void AddOneSecond(struct Time *timePtr)
{
    timePtr->seconds++;

    if (timePtr->seconds == 60)
    {
        timePtr->seconds = 00;
        timePtr->minutes += 1;
    }

    if (timePtr->minutes == 60)
    {
        timePtr->minutes = 00;
        timePtr->hours += 1;
    }
}

int CheckForErrors(struct Time timeVars, char charOne, char charTwo)
{
    auto int isInputValid = true;

    if ((timeVars.hours < 0) || (timeVars.hours > 24))
    {
        isInputValid = false;
        puts("The 'hours' value is invalid.");
    }

    if ((timeVars.minutes < 0) || (timeVars.minutes > 59))
    {
        isInputValid = false;
        puts("The 'minutes' value is invalid.");
    }

    if ((timeVars.seconds < 0) || (timeVars.seconds > 59))
    {
        isInputValid = false;
        puts("The 'seconds' value is invalid.");
    }

    if ((':' != charOne) || (':' != charTwo))
    {
        isInputValid = false;
        puts("The 'colon' value is invalid.");
    }

    return isInputValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below scanf statement You can get the input , but checking wrong input becomes more complex and You need to press enter key in the middle of your input.

```
scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", &userInput.hours
                          , &firstColon
                          , &userInput.minutes
                          , &secondColon
                          , &userInput.seconds);
```

Read string With `fgets()` in this format `HH:MM:SS`

Here you can check length , and you can check 0,1 indexes , 3,4 indexes and 6,7 index of this string are they digits or not ?

Also check `:` with the help of `strchr()`  or Check 2,5 indexes of string

after checking, if you want to convert hours into value

```
hours=(str[0]-'0') * 10 +(str[1]-'0');   
// use same for minutes and seconds
```

You can also use `strtol()` or `atoi()` for conversion,`strtol()` returns `long int` if you decide to use this you need to change type of hours,minutes,seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have a question, though. How does this line work, exactly? `(str[0]-'0') * 10 +(str[1]-'0');`

Comment: That will convert hours part of string to int value of hours.For example if you give input 12:32:30 , then `str[0] is '1' and '1'-'0' this will become 1`. and `str[1] is '2' and '2'-'0' will become 2`, finally `str[0]-'0') * 10 +(str[1]-'0');` this will result 12

Comment: Okay, and the `'0'` part makes it so that it's 'subtracting' characters, and that's where the conversion happens?

Comment: Yes. exactly. character digits are not actual integer digits if you substract character zero from them you will get integer digits. 48 is ASCII value for '0' and 57 is ASCII value for '9' substacting characters means substracting their ASCII values